# SQL Server 2008 R2 Template Field Length

Tags: sql-server

I've been asked a question I'm not sure the answer to.  If a template field length is set to 250 characters but then is changed to 1000, what would happen when an upgrade happens and sets the field length back to 250?  Would all of the data past 250 that was in that field when the length was set to 1000 be truncated in the column?  Or would the data still be in the column but only 250 characters would be viewable in the template?

Answer (score 2):

If there are any larger data, than 250 characters, it will throw an error like:

```
String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.
```

You will have to manually truncate the data:

```
UPDATE table SET Column=LEFT(Column, 250);
```

And then you can finally resize the column:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN Column nvarchar(250), null;
```

Comment: I should rephrase to say that we are importing the template and not updating it.  So when the import happens with the column being length 250, it does truncate all the data that was in those column row to 250 characters again, meaning we've lost data.  Is there a way to stop that from happening, other than updating the column in the template being imported?

Comment: No, you will have to store the data in a larger column, or have a multiple columns of 250 characters lenght and store the template in a multiple parts. Or use different way how to store your template data (binary, blob...)